# Glass Effect - Artistic Effect

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graphics

I wish to give an effect to images, where the resultant image would appear as if we are looking at it through a textured glass (not plain/smooth)... Please help me in writing an algo to generate such an effect.

Here's [an example](http://picasaweb.google.com/megha19sudan/ArtisticEffects) of the type of effect I'm looking for

The first image is the original image and the second image is the output im looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Begin by creating a noise map with dimensions `(width + 1) x (height + 1)`that will be used displace the original image. I suggest using some sort of [perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) so that the displacement is not to random. Here's a good [link](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) on how to generate perlin noise.

Once we have the noise we can do something like this:

```
Image noisemap; //size is (width + 1) x (height + 1) gray scale values in [0 255] range
Image source; //source image
Image destination; //destination image
float displacementRadius = 10.0f; //Displacemnet amount in pixels
for (int y = 0; y < source.height(); ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < source.width(); ++x) {
        const float n0 = float(noise.getValue(x, y)) / 255.0f;
        const float n1 = float(noise.getValue(x + 1, y)) / 255.0f;
        const float n2 = float(noise.getValue(x, y + 1)) / 255.0f;
        const int dx = int(floorf((n1 - n0) * displacementRadius + 0.5f));
        const int dy = int(floorf((n2 - n0) * displacementRadius + 0.5f));
        const int sx = std::min(std::max(x + dx, 0), source.width() - 1); //Clamp
        const int sy = std::min(std::max(y + dy, 0), source.height() - 1); //Clamp
        const Pixel& value = source.getValue(sx, sy);
        destination.setValue(x, y, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer you a specific example, but the [gamedev](http://gamedev.net) forums & articles sections have lots of gold for image processing, 3d rendering, and the like. 
For instance, here is [an article](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/imageproc/page2.asp) talking about using convolution matrices to apply similar effects to images that might be a good starting point.